# How to take the length of a column using vba-access

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Name

henry
james
larry
```

Hello everyone I am trying to take the length of a column using vba- access so that I can loop through each value in the column but I can not find any resource online which points this out I was thinking it would be something like this:

```
for (i= 1 to Name.Count)

next
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looping through recordset with VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579290/looping-through-recordset-with-vba)

Answer (score -1):

To return the length of a string in VBA, you can use `Len(String)`.  If you want to return the length of a string within a column in a query, you can use `Len([ColumnName])`.

Comment: OP is trying to loop through the recordset; not get the string length.

Comment: That wasn't his question.  How if he wanted to loop through each character of a string for each record in the recordset?

Comment: "So that I can loop through each value in the column"

Comment: Yes: "So that I can loop through each value in the column".  Looping through each value in a column is not the same as traversing the recordset itself.  You could traverse a recordset without ever referring to the values in its fields.

Comment: I am trying to loop through the record set not the string.